# Why A Mismatch Between ubuntu-drivers list and Additional Drivers List?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and have both an Intel GPU and Nvidia GeForce GTX 860M graphics card. Unfortunately Ubuntu is not recognizing my Nvidia card so I'm trying to figure out the proper resolution.

Following is the command and output I get when trying to identify what drivers are installed on my system:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
nvidia-364
nvidia-367
intel-microcode
nvidia-340
nvidia-370
nvidia-358
nvidia-361
```

When I access the Additional Drivers tab of Software and Updates, the driver that is apparently selected for my nvidia card is "Using X.Org X Server -- Nouveau display driver"

My question: Why does the ubuntu-drivers command correctly identify all drivers that show up in the Additional Drivers tab except for the X.Org Server entry?  Why the mismatch?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "mismatch".

"X.Org X Server -- Nouveau display driver" is a default open-source driver. When you select this option, all proprietary drivers are uninstalled.

`ubuntu-drivers list` command shows only available proprietary vendor drivers.

And your output does not mean that any of proprietary drivers are installed.

Comment: Thank you. Note I never selected the X.Org option so why is Ubuntu using that?   So
ubuntu-list doesn't list the drivers on my computer but the drivers  available for download from the repo - proprietary AND otherwise as one bit of advice I saw was to NOT use proprietary drivers but the open source drivers. The ubuntu-list matches the PPA list and not the NVIDIA list that was there before I did the PPA  command.
And  the Additional Drivers lists the drivers available in the repo and the driver in use.  

Have I correctly described it?

Comment: Ubuntu is ising X.Org by default. I do not know what is `ubuntu-list`.